# can we check match() function with a string variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have condition to check a match function with which data comes from service as below

```
var a = "daadvavda";
var b = "/[a-zA-Z]/g";
var c = a.match(b); 
console.log(c) 
// output will be null
```

How can i rectify this problem. I get the correct output in the code below

```
var c = a.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g);
console.log(c) 
//output :(9) ["d", "a", "a", "d", "v", "a", "v", "d", "a"]
// this is the output i needed
```

I can't give my data like this

> match(/[a-zA-Z]/g)

because get this data from service

Comment: Your regex is not regex but a string, make `var b = "/[a-zA-Z]/g";` as `var b = /[a-zA-Z]/g;`

Comment: @Redu  the problem with me is that I don't know how to convert a string into regex. Now I got it. And thanks for ur response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st off remove `"`s from pattern, it should be `var b = /[a-zA-Z]/g;`

2nd if you want to use string, use `RegExp`

```
var a = "daadvavda";
var b = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]", "g");
```

#### match

```
console.log(a.match(b)); 
//Output: (9) ["d", "a", "a", "d", "v", "a", "v", "d", "a"]
```

#### `regex.test()`

```
console.log(b.test(a)); 
//Output: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Maxim Shoustin

Answer (score 2):

to use a dynamic string as a pattern, you can make it work like

```
var a = "daadvavda";
var b = new RegExp("stringYouGetFromService", 'g');
var c = a.match(b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for u help @vnt

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string that contains a regexp with it's delimiters (`/`) and switches (`/gi`) like in this case (`"/[a-z]/gi"`), then you have to create a regexp object from that string and then use it. However to do that we have to strip out the part of the regexp between the delimiters `/`.

```js
var a = "daadvavda",
    b = "/[a-zA-Z]/g",
   rs = b.split("/"),
    r = new RegExp(rs[1],rs[2]),
    c = a.match(r); 
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. And Your explanation for my question very  is good

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `RegExp` object. Consider reading the documentation for [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thanks for your help @glennsl